# Same Value in hidden field with subsequent post back

Tags: c#, dropdown, hidden-field

I have an **hidden field** (hdn_vill) in Content place holder it initialises only when post back occurs but with every drop down selected changed event it concatenating same value  in hdn_vill with comma separate(eg:"2,2,2,2,2,")

Page load Event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Request.QueryString["vill"] != null)
                    hdn_vill.Value = (Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(CommonFunction.TripleDESDecrypt(Request.QueryString["vill"].ToString())).ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

And below is  Selected Event Changed Event

```
protected void ddl_Igrs_khata_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddl_Igrs_khata.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {

            FillOwnerDetail(ddl_Igrs_owner, 0,Convert.ToInt32(Encoder.HtmlEncode(hdn_vill.Value)));

        }

    }
```

HiddenField Control

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdn_vill" runat="server" Value="" />
```

Drop down Control

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Igrs_khata" runat="server" Width="100px" Font-Size="16px"
                            ForeColor="Black" Visible="false" class="" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_Igrs_khata_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            Height="30px" AutoPostBack="True">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Fill Owner Detail Function

```
protected void FillOwnerDetail(DropDownList ddl, int flag, string khatano)
    {
        try
        {
            LRCBl objlrcbl = new LRCBl();
            Checks ch = new Checks();
            int count = 0;

            if (!ch.IsValidNum(hdn_vill.Value) && !ch.IsValidNum(hdn_areaunit.Value))
            {
                //DataTable dt = objlrcbl.Usp_Ownership_wise_mutation("Get_owner_Detail_IGRSRahan_Khata", Convert.ToString(Encoder.HtmlEncode(hdn_vill.Value)), "", khatano, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
                DataTable dt = objlrcbl.IGRS_RahanamaMut("", 9, Convert.ToInt32(Encoder.HtmlEncode(hdn_vill.Value)), khatano, 0, "", 0, regno);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    ddl.DataSource = dt;
                    ddl.DataTextField = "oname";
                    ddl.DataValueField = "unique_id";
                    ddl.DataBind();
                    count++;
                }
                if (count > 0 && count < 2)
                {
                    ddl_Igrs_owner.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("चुने", "0"));
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Binding value is not corrected check the value

Comment: "its been two days" might be an excuse for the poorly formed question, but it's not going to help you in getting an answer. Take a break, then ask the question in a way so that others can clearly understand the problem and the desired behavior. Unclear what you are asking as is.

Comment: is it `web forms`?

Comment: show the code, like what happens in dropdown selection changed event, where are you initializing hidden field, what's there in page load

Comment: yes it is an web form @anete.anetes  

<asp:HiddenField ID="hdn_vill" runat="server" Value="" />

Comment: now the question is properly formatted please have a look again. @anete.anetes

Comment: @Mickey you setting `hdn_vill.Value` somewhere else

Comment: i m not setting hdn_vill anywhere apart from Load event

Comment: There's still a bulk of inconsistencies... like `FillOwnerDetail` taking 3 parameters and being called with one parameter. `Request.QueryString["vill"]` who's origin is nowhere to be found in the question and the fact that `hdn_vill.Value` is only written once in a no-postback case is not making it better... there is most certainly some relevant code that's not part of the question.

Comment: values gets added with comma (eg:"3,3,3,") every post back request from web control.

Comment: not just this hidden field (hdn_vill) if i add a new hidden field control its value repeat its self like (",,,")

Comment: @grek40  all the other hidden fields are also has the same value eg ",,,,,".
Please let me know if you need more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your client code should look like this:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdn_vill" />
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropDownList" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
/* Populate the control */
</asp:DropDownList>
```

whilst your server code should look like this:

```
protected void dropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hdn_vill.Value = string.Format("{0}{1},", hdn_vill.Value, dropDownList.SelectedValue);
}
```

This is as simple as it gets, can't do any better without seeing your code and knowing what the problem is.

Comment: please see question again i will try to explain it better than before

Comment: with every drop down item selection hdn_vill concatenate with its own value (eg:"2,2,2,2,2,")

Comment: @Mickey So what exactly do you want it to do? You do not want your hidden field value to concatenate the selected value? I still don't quite understand the question, as there is no question at all but simply a statement of what your code is doing.

Comment: i just want to know why there is multiple value in hdn_vill even when i not doing anything with hdn_vill in ddl_Igrs_khata_SelectedIndexChanged event

Comment: What does FillOwnerDetail do? Copy & Paste this function to your main question.

Comment: Are there any more events attached to your DropDownList, other than OnSelectedIndexChanged?

Comment: upon adding new hidden field the result are same  it has the value like ",,,,,,".